# Phonecall tracking

Tags: android

im trying to track phone call states, and log phone numbers, name if exists in contacts and date started and ended. I would like to do it in background, so i write it as a service, its my first time working with services and im getting a RuntimeException. I m saving data in SharedPreferences locally (in future it would be pushed to server) and only would like to display it with a toast if it is possible. Here are the classes:

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context m_context;

String m_number = null;
String m_startTime = null;
String m_endTime = null;

SharedPreferences m_sharedPrefs;
Editor editor;

public String PREFS_NUMBER;
public String PREFS_START_TIME;
public String PREFS_END_TIME;
public String PREFS__NAME;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    m_sharedPrefs = m_context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    editor = m_sharedPrefs.edit();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null)
        return;

    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if ((state != null) && 
(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
        Log.i("TAG", "incoming call");

        Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
        String[] projection = { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };

        Cursor cursor = m_context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, 
projection, null, null, null);

        int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String contactName = cursor.getString(columnName);

        if(contactName != null) {
            editor.putString(PREFS__NAME, contactName);
        }

        m_number = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        editor.putString(PREFS_NUMBER, m_number);
        editor.commit();

    } else if(state == null) {
        Log.i("TAG", "outgoing call");

        Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
        String[] projection = { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };

        Cursor cursor = m_context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, 
projection, null, null, null);

        int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String contactName = cursor.getString(columnName);

        if(contactName != null) {
            editor.putString(PREFS__NAME, contactName);
        }

        m_number = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        editor.putString(PREFS_NUMBER, m_number);
        editor.commit();

    } else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        Log.i("TAG", "off hook");

        Time dtstart = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        dtstart.setToNow();

        m_startTime = dtstart.format("%k:%M:%S");

        editor.putString(PREFS_START_TIME, m_startTime);
        editor.commit();

    } else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        Log.i("TAG", "on idle");

        Time dtend = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        dtend.setToNow();

        m_endTime = dtend.format("%k:%M:%S");

        editor.putString(PREFS_END_TIME, m_endTime);
        editor.commit();
    }


}

}
```

service:

```
    public class TrackerService extends Service {
PhoneStateBroadcastReciever receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    receiver = new PhoneStateBroadcastReciever();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "starting service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

activity:

```
public class TrackerSettingsActivity extends Activity {
public static int TIME_DELAY = 0;
PhoneStateBroadcastReciever prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tracker_settings);

EditText timerDelay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Set_Timer);
String text = timerDelay.getText().toString();
TIME_DELAY = Integer.valueOf(text);

startService(new Intent(this, TrackerService.class));   
updateDataLocally();

}

private void updateDataLocally() {
    SharedPreferences m_sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    String number = m_sharedPrefs.getString(prefs.PREFS_NUMBER, "1");
    String startTime = m_sharedPrefs.getString(prefs.PREFS_START_TIME, "2");
    String endTime = m_sharedPrefs.getString(prefs.PREFS_END_TIME, "3");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number + " " + startTime + " " + 
endTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

and settings.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_Set_Timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tv_settimer"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_Set_Timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_Set_Timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Set_Timer"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_Confirm"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText_Set_Timer"
    android:text="@string/bn_confirm" />


10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40a1e065
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): , tls=0x6a5e6f00, arg=0x400b3008
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40a1e065,         
tls=0x6a6e6f00, arg=0x400b4010
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40a1e065
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): , tls=0x6a6e6f00, arg=0x400b4010
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40a1e065, 
tls=0x6a7e6f00, arg=0x68e691c8
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40a1e065
10-29 14:51:14.028: D/libc(14050): , tls=0x6a7e6f00, arg=0x68e691c8
10-29 14:51:14.048: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x4017e509, 
tls=0x6aae4f00, arg=0x68e698b0
10-29 14:51:14.048: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x4017e509
10-29 14:51:14.048: D/libc(14050): , tls=0x6aae4f00, arg=0x68e698b0
10-29 14:51:14.048: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x4017e509, 
tls=0x6abe4f00, arg=0x688b28e8
10-29 14:51:14.048: D/libc(14050): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x4017e509
10-29 14:51:14.048: D/libc(14050): , tls=0x6abe4f00, arg=0x688b28e8
10-29 14:51:14.078: E/Trace(14050): error opening trace file: No such file or directory
(2)
10-29 14:51:14.088: I/System.out(14050): Sending WAIT chunk
10-29 14:51:14.088: W/ActivityThread(14050): Application hr.hyperactive.tracker is 
waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-29 14:51:14.289: I/System.out(14050): Debugger has connected
10-29 14:51:14.289: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:14.489: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:14.689: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:14.889: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:15.090: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:15.290: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:15.500: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:15.700: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:15.900: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:16.101: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:16.301: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:16.501: I/System.out(14050): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-29 14:51:16.701: I/System.out(14050): debugger has settled (1457)
10-29 14:51:17.072: D/skia(14050): new locale hr_US
10-29 14:51:22.808: W/jdwp(14050): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
```

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're getting this RuntimeException because `m_context` is null:

```
m_sharedPrefs = m_context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
```

Try to use the onReceive's `context` instead.

**edited:**

try this:

```
m_sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Comment: actually this part is working from the beginning, parsing string to int was the error. But now i cannot parse it to int, i dont know why...